# How can I decrypt this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, encryption

```
var _0x9218=["\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x69\x63","\x73\x75\x63\x6B\x66\x75\x63\x6B","\x37\x69\x37","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x73\x72\x63","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x69\x64\x67\x65\x74\x73\x2E\x61\x6D\x75\x6E\x67\x2E\x75\x73\x2F\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x69\x63\x2E\x6A\x73","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x68\x65\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65"];var _0x9bba=[_0x9218[0],_0x9218[1],_0x9218[2],_0x9218[3],_0x9218[4],_0x9218[5],_0x9218[6],_0x9218[7],_0x9218[8],_0x9218[9],_0x9218[10],_0x9218[11]];var _0x6f57=[_0x9bba[0],_0x9bba[1],_0x9bba[2],_0x9bba[3],_0x9bba[4],_0x9bba[5],_0x9bba[6],_0x9bba[7],_0x9bba[8],_0x9bba[9],_0x9bba[10],_0x9bba[11]];var _wau=_wau||[];_wau[_0x6f57[3]]([_0x6f57[0],_0x6f57[1],_0x6f57[2]]);(function (){var _0x1962x4=document[_0x6f57[5]](_0x6f57[4]);_0x1962x4[_0x6f57[6]]=true;_0x1962x4[_0x6f57[7]]=_0x6f57[8];document[_0x6f57[11]](_0x6f57[10])[0][_0x6f57[9]](_0x1962x4);} )();
```

Comment: It's not really encrypted. It's just obfuscated. Run it through a JS beautifier and then manually pick it apart.

Comment: This question comes into StackOverflow frequently. Better use the search.

Answer (score 1):

It adds the script: `http://widgets.amung.us/classic.js` to the document.

I have no intention of checking what's in that script.

Answer (score 1):

It translates to this code:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");

script.async = true;
script.src = "http://widgets.amung.us/classic.js";

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

It's just visitor tracking: http://whos.amung.us/

Comment: Did you do that by hand, or with a tool?

Comment: By hand. Sublime Text 2 can rename variables, so it took like a minute.

Comment: I got this output from JS beautifier:

var _wau = _wau || [];
_wau[_0x6f57[3]]([_0x6f57[0], _0x6f57[1], _0x6f57[2]]);
(function () {
    var _0x1962x4 = document[_0x6f57[5]](_0x6f57[4]);
    _0x1962x4[_0x6f57[6]] = true;
    _0x1962x4[_0x6f57[7]] = _0x6f57[8];
    document[_0x6f57[11]](_0x6f57[10])[0][_0x6f57[9]](_0x1962x4);
})();

I just need this string in readable format:
var _wau = _wau || [];
_wau[_0x6f57[3]]([_0x6f57[0], _0x6f57[1], _0x6f57[2]]);

Comment: `_0x6f57` and the other thing are just arrays. Put `["\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x69\x63","\x73\x75\x63\x6B\x66\x75\x63\x6B","\x37\x69\x37","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x73\x72\x63","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x69\x64\x67\x65\x74\x73\x2E\x61\x6D\x75\x6E\x67\x2E\x75\x73\x2F\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x69\x63\x2E\x6A\x73","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x68\x65\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65"];` into a JS console and see the text.

Comment: Thanks Blender :)
I just used this extension and it worked for me